# Using a t.test inside dplyr summarise after grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(price_avg = t.test(
    . %>% filter(color == "E") %$% price,
    . %>% filter(color == "I") %$% price )$p.value)
```

I'm trying to get the result of a t.test to apply by group. In this example finding if there is a significant difference in price of colour when looking at the same cut. The result I get is:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE.
```

Comment: thanks, have added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(price_avg = t.test(price[color=="E"], price[color=="I"])$p.value)

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   cut       price_avg
#   <ord>         <dbl>
# 1 Fair       3.90e- 3
# 2 Good       1.46e-12
# 3 Very Good  2.44e-39
# 4 Premium    7.27e-52
# 5 Ideal      7.63e-62
```

The **problem with your solution** is that `.` won't get the subset of your dataset (based on your grouping), but the whole dataset. Check by doing this:

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(d = list(.))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#     cut       d                     
#     <ord>     <list>                
#   1 Fair      <tibble [53,940 x 10]>
#   2 Good      <tibble [53,940 x 10]>
#   3 Very Good <tibble [53,940 x 10]>
#   4 Premium   <tibble [53,940 x 10]>
#   5 Ideal     <tibble [53,940 x 10]>
```

An alternative solution would be this:

```
diamonds %>% 
  nest(-cut) %>%
  mutate(price_avg = map_dbl(data, ~t.test(
                                      .x %>% filter(color == "E") %$% price,
                                      .x %>% filter(color == "I") %$% price )$p.value))

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   cut       data                  price_avg
#   <ord>     <list>                    <dbl>
# 1 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 x 9]>  7.63e-62
# 2 Premium   <tibble [13,791 x 9]>  7.27e-52
# 3 Good      <tibble [4,906 x 9]>   1.46e-12
# 4 Very Good <tibble [12,082 x 9]>  2.44e-39
# 5 Fair      <tibble [1,610 x 9]>   3.90e- 3
```

This works with `filter` because you are able to pass to `filter` the appropriate subset of your data (i.e. column `data`) each time.

Comment: ah, I'm getting a little too obsessed with dplyr it seems. Is there anyway to use filter() in the summarise?#

Comment: @pluke Not well, no. I think the “recommended” approach would be via `tidyr::nest` + purrr + broom instead of pure dplyr.

Comment: I agree with @KonradRudolph , but how do you think to use `filter` inside `summarise`? And why?

Comment: as shown above, I wanted to use filter(color == "E") instead of base R

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that using only `dplyr`. However, note that the problem is not the `filter` command, but the fact that you can't use the right subset of data to `filter` from. You can use `purrr` in this way: `diamonds %>% 
  nest(-cut) %>%
  mutate(price_avg = map_dbl(data, ~t.test(
                                      .x %>% filter(color == "E") %$% price,
                                      .x %>% filter(color == "I") %$% price )$p.value))`

Answer (score 6):

There *must* be a better way of doing this. I’d probably go with Antonios’ approach but I’m tempted to not use `filter`, and instead spread the prices for different colours into list columns. Unfortunately the best code I could come up with is even longer as a result:

```
diamonds %>%
    group_by(cut, color) %>%
    summarize(price = list(price)) %>%
    spread(color, price) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(price_avg = map_dbl(data, ~ t.test(.x$E[[1L]], .x$I[[1L]])$p.value))
```

The idea here is to get two list columns, `I` and `E`, for the price of diamonds of the respective colour. We can now run the t-test on these two columns (but unfortunately we need to unlist them for that to work).

I’m mainly putting this here as a conversation starter. Clearly this isn’t code you’d ever want to write but I believe that there should be a short, logical way of expressing this logic (either this is already possible and I’m overlooking it, or the tidy data API needs to be augmented).

Alternatively we can use the formula API for `t.test`:

```
diamonds %>%
    filter(color %in% c('E', 'I')) %>%
    nest(-cut) %>%
    mutate(price_avg = map_dbl(data, ~ t.test(price ~ color, .x)$p.value))
```

For completeness, here’s the same using `broom::tidy` (this gives back more columns than just the p-value):

```
diamonds %>%
    filter(color %in% c('E', 'I')) %>%
    nest(-cut) %>%
    mutate(test = map(data, ~ tidy(t.test(price ~ color, .x)))) %>%
    unnest(test)
```

The result of this is a table like this:

```
  cut       data             estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic  p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                  alternative
  <ord>     <list>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>                   <fct>
1 Fair      <tibble [1 × 7]>   -1003.     3682.     4685.     -2.91 3.90e- 3      327.   -1682.     -324. Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
2 Good      <tibble [1 × 7]>   -1655.     3424.     5079.     -7.19 1.46e-12      827.   -2107.    -1203. Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
3 Very Good <tibble [1 × 7]>   -2041.     3215.     5256.    -13.4  2.44e-39     1860.   -2339.    -1743. Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
4 Premium   <tibble [1 × 7]>   -2407.     3539.     5946.    -15.5  7.27e-52     2405.   -2711.    -2103. Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
5 Ideal     <tibble [1 × 7]>   -1854.     2598.     4452.    -17.0  7.63e-62     3081.   -2069.    -1640. Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
```